# How to show error rather than 500 page in Flask

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, amazon-ec2

I am facing an issue for the last few hours, my issue is that I want to see the error page instead of the 500 Error page.

Below is the page which is showing for me on error but I want the exact error so that I can fix the error.
Here is my code of run.py file.

I make the Debug = True but still the 500 page shows rather than error.

I have deployed this code to AWS ec2 instance is there any kind of restart needed to change the effect of Debug???

I am in real trouble please give me some suggestions.

```
from isense_server import create_app


app = create_app()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is the 500 page which shows instead of error.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that your flask is started separately, so that the debug mode can display detailed error messages. No gunicorn+gevent or supervisor...

Comment: what do you mean by separately? @Trock

Comment: I used a translation. I mean run this `python run.py`(your startup file). Not use nginx proxy，or gunicorn, gevent tools to startup.